# How can i set a Django render block value in the "with template tag", in Django Template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am displaying dynamic title based on different views in the Django application, i want to set the same title on the 3 meta tags in my base.html file,
which gets extended in all other templates.

This works correctly, when i set a string on title variable:

```
{% with title='TEST'%}
    <title>{% block page-title %}{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{ agency.name }}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{title}}" />
{% endwith %}
```

I want to set this dynamic title like:

```
{% with title="{% block page-title %}{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{agency.name }}{% endblock %}"%}
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{title}}" />
{% endwith %}
```

But when i do like this, then i don't get the value in title variable:

How can i set it to a variable in with template tag and then re-use that variable in other tags? 
or is there any other way of doing it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [block assignment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-assignments) feature:

```
{% with %}
    {% set title %}{% block page-title %}{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{ agency.name }}{% endblock %}{% endset %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{title}}" />
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I have django template. It is giving me error as: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment.

Comment: I suppose you can safely remove 'with'.

Comment: Error: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: I guess, this is for flask, not for django templates. I have django templates.

Comment: okay, No problem. I am looking for the same thing in Django Template.